# Examples of simple beautiful PhD theses

Tags: memoir, book-design, lyx-layouts

Please share the simplest, most beautiful PhD / master's theses you've ever seen. Looking for ideas for layout (medicine). Source code appreciated.

Comment: Should this be community-wiki?

Comment: You can find some theses between answers to [Showcase of beautiful ...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/)

Comment: IMHO beauty is in the eye of the beholder. `:)` I strongly believe this question would be better off merged in the showcase thread indicated by Ignasi than standing as a question on its own. Note that many universities have strict policies on how a thesis should look, so at the end of the day you are stuck with their requirements.

Answer (score 31):

Aaron Turon created [a beautiful thesis](http://aturon.github.io/academic/turon-thesis.pdf). His colophon:

> This document was typeset using LATEX, with a mixture of
> classicthesis developed by
> André Miede and tufte-latex, which is based on Edward Tufte’s Beautiful Evidence. The
> bibliography was processed by Biblatex.
>
> Robert Slimbach’s Minion
> Pro acts as both the text and display type-face. Sans-serif text is typeset in
> Slimbach and Carol Twombly’s Myriad Pro; monospaced text uses Jim
> Lyles’s Bitstream Vera Mono (“Bera Mono”). Donald Knuth’s Computer
> Modern is used throughout, but I’m not saying where.

Comment: It would be nice to have the sources.

Comment: Is the .tex file anywhere?

Comment: I wrote him an email asking for it, but did not get an answer. Thus, I tried to rebuild his thesis template for my own and will make it available, once I finished writing (hopefully soonish).

Comment: Hello @asante. Did you manage to rebuild the template? Otherwise I might do that. Thank you.

Comment: @burningfuses I'm not finished with writing my thesis, but an (almost finished) draft is available here: https://github.com/pfasante/phd_thesis -- disclaimer: the template is most certainly not well written and can use some improvements, but I'm not experienced with writing latex packages at all. So I'm happy about all feedback.

Comment: @asante Thanks a lot! I'll try to fix any problems I might encounter.

Answer (score 9):

The [Maggi Memoir Thesis Template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/maggi-memoir-thesis) is very nice, originally by Federico Maggi.  It is a double sided, thin layout that includes index, acronyms, and custom picked fonts.

There seem to be relatively few truly beautiful templates for theses out there, probably because the formatting requirements that most are created to follow simply weren't designed with good looks in mind.  I know that was true of my school's requirements.  Many are simply Word templates that have been transitioned to LaTeX.

Maggi Memoir Thesis Title Page:

[image: Maggi Memoir Thesis Title Page]

Comment: is maggi memori thesis for book printing? if so what size book could be printed based on the template?

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to [cslstr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/47522/cslstr)'s answer, you might want to take a look to the other templates found on [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses) (besides the Maggi Memoir Thesis Template).

Other good resources with ready-made templates include:

- [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/), which has a "mixed bag" of templates.
- [Thesis-Template](http://www.thesis-template.com/), which has various templates from Universities worldwide.
- [UK-TUG](http://uk.tug.org/training/thesis/), which has templates from some UK Universities.

A lot of contributions can also be found on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/).

I agree that "beauty is in the eye of the beholder", so probably you should pick one you like by yourself. Besides, as it has been mentioned, at the end of the day you'll have to abide to your University's standard.